# Angular on S3, refresh causes "AccessDenied" response

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have an angular 5 app - that I've been running locally, had it running with a nodjs server on heroku fine, but when I put it in an S3 bucket, behind cloudfront  and i hit refresh I get this.

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>217...1C</RequestId>
<HostId>
yu2de...dr0=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it only when you hit refresh? Are you using routing? If so, take a look at https://medium.com/@peatiscoding/here-is-how-easy-it-is-to-deploy-an-angular-spa-single-page-app-as-a-static-website-using-s3-and-6aa446db38ef#cf55

Comment: PERFECT! - post as answer I'll up vote and select - this was EXACTLY what I needed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to configure Cloudfront to handle the routing, so that all routes get redirected to `index.html`

Take a look at [this](https://medium.com/@peatiscoding/here-is-how-easy-it-is-to-deploy-an-angular-spa-single-page-app-as-a-static-website-using-s3-and-6aa446db38ef#cf55) for more info

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a simple HTML S3 site for testing in DEV and using the default assigned domain (not using cloudfront), set error page to the same as your start page (index.html). Then when the page is refreshed, it reloads with the same route, just like a traditional website that is not a SPA.